# VB function with multiple outputs

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to create a VB function with multiple outputs.  Note: I am not looking for an array containing me three outputs or a variable using delimitters

Answer (score 2):

If you're running .NET4 then you could use one of the new `Tuple` types (eg, [`Tuple(Of T1, T2)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx)):

```
Public Function ReturnTwoValues() As Tuple(Of String, Integer)
    Return Tuple.Create("Test", 42)
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, pass your parameters to the function by reference (byref) you can then modify them in the body of the function.

Answer (score 0):

C# has the [out keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx):

```
void TestFunc(int x, ref int y, out int z) {
  x++;  
  y++;
  z = 5;
}
```

VB has no equivalent as explicit.  You can only pass values using [ByRef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c84t73c2%28VS.71%29.aspx):

```
Sub TestFunc(ByVal x As Integer, ByRef y As Integer, ByRef z As Integer)
  x += 1
  y += 1 
  z = 5 
End Sub
```

Details of VB/C# differences [here](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html).